# Google App Script external API return error 406

Tags: google-apps-script, urlfetch, http-status-code-406

I'm trying to fetch a URL using optional advanced parameters in GAS:

```
function myFunction() {
  var options = {};
  options = {
    headers: {
      Authorization: 'Bearer ?????',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
  };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(<url>, options);
}
```

I always get:

> Request failed for  returned code 406 (line 52, file "Project").

HTTPResponse:

> SyntaxError: Empty JSON string

I did the same fetching in Excel Power Query:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(<URL>, [Headers=[Authorization="Bearer 
?????????????", ContentType="application/json"]])),
```

And it works, it works also using Postman...

What's the problem with GAS? Please help me! Thanks in advance to everybody.
Andrea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`406` error is because content negotiation between server and client has failed. While setting `Content-Type`, It's possible that the accepted return content is also advertised as `'application/json'` by Power query and Postman, but `UrlFetchApp` doesn't do the same. Adding a explicit `Accept` header solves this:

```
Accept: 'application/json'
```

#### References:

- [406 Not acceptable/Web MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)
- [RFC7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.6)

Comment: Brilliant, thank you. My error was in another software but this solved it!