# Google Apps Script Blocked by Mod Security Error 406

Tags: google-apps-script, web-scraping, urlfetch

I want to scrape a website using Google Apps Script. unfortunately, it giving me an error 406.

below is the full details of the error:

```
resp:
"<html><head><title>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</title><head><body><h1>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</h1><p>Generally a 406 error is caused because a request has been blocked by Mod Security. If you belie…"
```

Below is a sample of the code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

var options = {

  'method' : 'get',

  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
 
Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',

  'muteHttpExceptions': true,

  Authorization: 'Bearer ?????',

  Accept: 'application/json',

  'Content-Type': 'application/json',

}


function scrapeJobs(){

  var result = [];

  for(var i =1; i <= 2; i++){

    var url = 'https://www.xxxxxxx/page/'  + i;

   var resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options,).getContentText();

var $ = Cheerio.load(resp);

var jobList = $("#titlo > strong > a");

var urls =  jobList.map(function() {return $(this).attr('href');}).toArray();

// debug code - outputs the urls it collected

console.log(urls);

for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {

  var data = scrapeJobDetails(urls[i]);

  if (data != null) {

    result.push(...data);

  }

  }

 }
```

I tried following the answer to a similar question asked here but no success. see the link below:

[Google App Script external API return error 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625841/google-app-script-external-api-return-error-406)

Comment: Your request only accepts `application/json`, but the website you want to scrape probably is `text/html`. Consider which headers you really want to set in your request.

Comment: hello @HeikoTheißen. thanks for your response. so, how should my header be then if website is text/html? edit my code please

Answer (score 1):

To fetch a website for scraping, simply use

```js
function myFunction() {
  Logger.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch('<url of website>', {
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  }).getContentText());
}
```

(When running `myFunction` in the Apps Script editor, this logs the contents of the website.)

The `muteHttpExceptions` is necessary if you want to scape also error pages like "404 Not Found". (Without it, such a page leads to a catchable exception.)

Comment: hello @HeikoTheißen . i have tried your solution but am still getting blocked by mod security error 406

Comment: What website are you trying to scrape?

Comment: Hi @HeikoTheißen. maybe share your full code. thanks

Comment: See my augmented answer.

Comment: Hi @HeikoTheißen. i made a mistake it : https://www.jobwebethiopia.com

Answer (score 0):

The reference to ModSecurity is very odd. ModSec does not return status code 406 unless with special configuration. So the whole "Generally a 406 error is caused because a request has been blocked by Mod Security ..." is probably a generic message misleading you here.