# Fetching an RSS Feed using Google Apps Script Returns 406 Error

Tags: rest, google-apps-script, google-sheets, rss, http-error

I've got a simple Google apps script that is fetching a series of RSS feeds:

```
for (let i = 0; i < rssUrls.length; i++) {
   const rssUrl = rssUrls[i];

   const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rssUrl);

   console.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

The URL that's failing is: http://tenfootpole.org/ironspike/?feed=rss2

The response I get is:

```
<html><head><title>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</title><head><body><h1>Error 406 - Not Acceptable</h1><p>Generally a 406 error is caused because a request has been blocked by Mod Security. If you believe that your request has been blocked by mistake please contact the web site owner.</p></body></html>
```

It works fine through the browser or POSTman - & even using the =IMPORTFEED() function in google sheets. Not sure what makes GAS unique?

This is the fix I made after reading [Google App Script external API return error 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52625841/google-app-script-external-api-return-error-406) & [Google Apps Script Blocked by Mod Security Error 406](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74941372/google-apps-script-blocked-by-mod-security-error-406) which seem related.

```
const options = {
  headers: {
    Accept: '*/*'
  },
  'muteHttpExceptions': true
};

const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rssUrl, options);

console.log(response.getContentText());
```

But I still get the same problem. I've tried various combinations of content type, encoding types and languages but I always the same error. I suspect I'm seeing a default response for something else? Any idea what?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether this is included in your expected direction, I proposed a workaround. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could correctly replicate your situation. Unfortunately, even when `Accept`, `Accept-Encoding`, and `Accept-Language` are used in the request header, the status code of 406 couldn't be removed. From this situation, I thought that your situation might be related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63024346). In this case, how about the following workaround?

In this workaround, when the response code is 406, the URL is requested using `IMPORTFEED` or `IMPORTDATA` on the Spreadsheet. Namely, a Spreadsheet is used as a temporal sheet for retrieving the data from the URL. By this, the values can be obtained.

#### Sample script:

This script used Spreadsheet. So, please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet. And, please set the sheet name. This sheet is used as a temporal sheet.

```js
function sample() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.
  const rssUrls = ["http://tenfootpole.org/ironspike/?feed=rss2", , ,]; // Please set your URLs.

  rssUrls.forEach(url => {
    const response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
    let res = "";
    const statusCode = response.getResponseCode();
    if (statusCode == 406) {
      const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
      sheet.clear();
      const range = sheet.getRange("A1");
      range.setFormula(`=IMPORTFEED("${url}")`);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      res = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().join("\n");
    } else if (statusCode == 200) {
      res = response.getContentText();
    } else {
      console.log(`Error occurs at "${url}".`);
      return;
    }

    console.log(res); // Here, you can confirm the retrieved value.

    // do something. Please set your script using the response value.

  });
}
```

- When this script is run, when the response code is 406, the value is retrieved using `IMPORTFEED` with a temporal sheet.
- If you want to use `IMPORTDATA` instead of `IMPORTFEED`, please modify it as follows.

  - From

    ```
      range.setFormula(`=IMPORTFEED("${url}")`);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      res = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().join("\n");
    ```
  - To

    ```
      range.setFormula(`=IMPORTDATA("${url}")`);
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
      res = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().map(r => r.filter(String).join(",")).join("\n");
    ```

#### References:

- [406 Not Acceptable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Class UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

Comment: By the way, if you want to clear the temporal sheet after the script is run, please add `range.clearContent()` just after the line of `res = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().join("\n");`.

Comment: Thanks - This solution worked  - it was what i was considering doing but your example helped a lot! 

Its certainly less reliable as the IMPORTFEED  function can take a little while to load - so i have to put a 1 second sleep in it - but as this is maybe 1 of >300 URLs that get called it not so bad.

Thanks!